# Android: is there a way to listen to fragment's enter/exit animations inside the fragment itself?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I have an activity and two fragments implementing master-detail flow.

when the detail fragment enters, it is animated to slide in from right to left.
the fragment also contains a FloatingActionMenu (https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton). Now I want to animate this fab after the enter and exit animation of detail fragment.

what I have done till now is:
hide the fab in fragments onCreate()
in onStart() added a postDelay() to show that fab with animation (I know this is not good)

So I wanted to know if there is a way to attach a listener to animator that is performing fragment enter and exit transition animations, so that I can animate the fab accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `public Animator onCreateAnimator(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim)` method. It called when a fragment loads an animation

`int transit` - transition type, see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html).

`boolean enter` - true if animation is enterAnimation

`int nextAnim` - the resource ID of the animation

For example:

```
@Override
public Animator onCreateAnimator(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
    Animator animator = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), nextAnim);
    if (nextAnim == R.animator.your_animator){
        animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });
    }
    return animator;
}
```

Comment: thanks that helped except that I am using v4 fragment and the method is `public Animation onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) `